# Analysis proof rational numbers and absolute

Tags: real-analysis

Let $r$ be a real number, show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exist two rational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x < r < y$ and $|x-y| < \epsilon$.

So I started off by thinking of examples of values that satisfy and if I let $\epsilon$ is equal to $1$, then $|x-y| < 1$ so there exist two cases $(x-y) < 1$ and $-x + y < 1$.

But I'm not sure how to formally prove it.

Comment: What do you already know about the distribution of rational numbers in the reals?

Comment: The rationals are "dense" in the reals: every open interval contains some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider rational numbers of the form

$$\frac{\lfloor kr \rfloor - 1}{k}, \frac{\lfloor kr \rfloor + 1}{k} $$

for some positive integer $k$

---

*Hint 2:*

Show that for every positive integer $k$,

$$\frac{\lfloor kr \rfloor - 1}{k} \ < \ r \ < \ \frac{\lfloor kr \rfloor + 1}{k} $$

Thus these two expressions are candidates for $x$ and $y$. Now, what value of $k$ will ensure that $|x - y| < \epsilon$?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure how this hint helps, can I get another hint haha

Comment: See the second hint!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a rational in $(r, r + \epsilon /2)$? How about $(r - \epsilon /2, r)$? If so, can you put a strict upper bound on their distance from each other?

Comment: $(r + \epsilon /4)$? and $(r - \epsilon /4)$ But what is the significance of $(\epsilon/2)$

Comment: I can only say, Think about it, do the arithmetic. Draw a picture!